# How to solve this problem 4

Tags: trigonometry

**Question** $1$:

Is
$\frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\left(\frac{{\sqrt{2*\sqrt{2*\sqrt{2}*...n}}}}{2}\right)$
always a rational number when each$*$ is either $+$ or $-$ and $n$ may or may not be infinite?

**Question** $2$

If its a rational number, then how is it related with the signs($*$) and the value of $n$?

I think both questions can be solved by using half angle formulas for sine and cosine but I am not able to do so.

Comment: Didn't you rather mean rational multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: Sure that you mean
$\arccos\left(\frac{{\large \sqrt{2*\sqrt{2*\sqrt{2}*...n}}}}{\pi}\right)$
and not 
$\frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\left(\sqrt{2*\sqrt{2*\sqrt{2}*...n}}\right)?$

Comment: I did it. But you should clarify two other possible issues: 
(1) Do the * always denote the same operation or can + and - be mixed?
(2) The $\arccos \sqrt{2}, \arccos \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2}},\dots$ are complex.

Comment: Its$\arccos{\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}}$, $*$ can be mixed